# move_uploaded_file failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

Quando envio uma foto para atualizar o perfil no sistema, retorna a seguinte falha:  move_uploaded_file(/isequi/public/assets/img/user_pic/062701-20160807-suicida.jpg):
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\isequi\sys\class\user.php

O ambiente para teste é windows 7 com xampp.

Código usado:

```
$this->picName = basename($_FILES['userPicture']['name']); 
        $this->picExtension = pathinfo($this->picName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $this->picSize = round($_FILES['userPicture']['size'] / 1000); 

        if($this->picSize == 0) {
            $functions -> generateJsonMsg('selectPicture', null, null, null, $message->message['selectPicture']);
        }
        if($this->picSize > 100)    {
            $functions -> generateJsonMsg('fileIsTooLarge', null, null, null, $message->message['fileIsTooLarge']);
        }
        $functions -> isInArray($this->picExtension, $this->arrayPictureExtensionPermitted, 'extensionNotAllowed', $message->message['extensionNotAllowed']);   

        $this->picName = date('sih-Ymd').'-'.$this->picName;
        $this->picNameDirectory = '/webpage/public/assets/img/user_pic/'.$this->picName;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userPicture']['tmp_name'], $this->picNameDirectory)) {
            try   {
                $this->conn = parent::getconnection();  
                $this->pQuery = $this->conn->prepare(   'update user_detail '.
                                                        'set ud_picture=:picName '.
                                                        'where fk_user_id=:sessionId '.
                                                        'limit 1'   );  
                $this->pQuery->execute(array(   ':picName' => $this->picName, 
                                                ':sessionId' => $session -> sessionId()     ));
                if($this->pQuery->errorCode() == 0) {
                    $functions -> generateJsonMsg('success', null, null, null, $message->message['iconSuccess']);
                }   
                else     {
                    throw new Exception();
                }                               
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                $tException = new tException();
                $tException -> newException($e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTraceAsString());
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Tem a certeza que a que quer apagar é a que estava lá antes do update e que esse ficheiro existe no caminho indicado no erro?

Comment: Eu fiz um teste inserindo um echo usando $_FILES['userPicture']['tmp_name'] e verifiquei se o arquivo temp estava lá, e não achei o arquivo .tmp.. O Diretóiro em questão /webpage/public/assets/img/user_pic/ existe

Comment: Não é esse que tem de ver, no caso da pergunta teria de ver se `062701-20160807-suicida.jpg` existe em `/isequi/public/assets/img/user_pic/`

Comment: Fala Miguel.. O arquivo não foi criado na pasta. Mudei permissão da pasta, mas continua dando a mesma falha.

Comment: O problema não é das permissões. `No such file or directory in ...` é porque não existe `/062701-20160807-suicida.jpg` ou o caminho está errado

Answer (score 1):

Já que é `Windows` tente colocar o caminho absoluto, como por exemplo:

**C:/pasta/onde/voce/vai/salvar/**

Além disso, verifique se essa pasta tem permissão total **(0777)**

O erro que retornou para você **"failed to open stream: No such file or directory"** diz que não foi possível abrir o diretório, ou seja, não existe.

Comment: Eu não mudei permissão na pasta, somente mudei o User Account Control para notificar quando tiver alguma mudança. Procurei bastante antes de postar a dúvida, para ver se existe alguma configuração no xampp ou windows e não achei nada de configuração para estes.

Comment: Valeu Alisson. Coloquei o caminho absoluto e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o erro não está no trecho de código que você passou, onde é chamada sua função? Está dando um erro é na Classe User; Provavelmente está sendo instanciada uma classe que não existe no repositório.

Comment: Existe uma chamada JQuery para o método chamado changePicture.php, este pertence a classe user.